# Position a .jpg/png vs .svg

Tags: css, svg

Laying out a page like this:

```
<div style="width:100%; height:auto;" > 
     <img style="width:100%; height:auto;" src="image.png">
</div>
```

Takes up the full width of the page, as expected. But if I replace the .png with .svg (converting the image with inkscape), there is a lot of white space on the left and right hand size, the image seems to take up a maximum of 1024 width, even though the image in inkscape gives it a well over 2000px width. Does css treat the two differently?

Comment: An SVG doesn't have a size. The "S" stands for "Scalable". Vectorizing a raster format like PNG won't usually work well.

Comment: Does the SVG image have width and height attributes? Does it have a viewBox? If it has a viewBox it has a fixed aspect ratio which would explain the whitespace.

Comment: [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/) gives a very good overview of the topic.